# WPF file header mappings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a simple application that maps the header row of a file into a table in the DB. I created a function that splits the header row on comma and then displays it in a textbox (one column on each line). Then I pull in all the columns from the DB and do the same thing. Next thing I do is an automap, which just checks to see if the column from the file matches exactly to the db column. If it does then it matches them and puts them in the center textbox like this: `Col1 : Col1`. The next step that I would like to be able to do is manually map the ones that weren't named the exact same. My thought was to be able to select the column on the left most textbox (show that the whole row is selected) and do the same for DB and once they both have a selection it adds that to the middle matched textbox. How can I match the columns from the header to bind it with a column from the db?

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnOpenFile" Padding="10" Click="btnOpenFile_Click" Content="Open file" Margin="30,8,594,356"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtEditor" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="30,105,518,10" />
    <Label Margin="30,68,649,319">Header from file</Label>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtEditor_db" Margin="525,105,23,10" />
    <Label Margin="525,68,72,319" Content="Column Mappings from db&#xD;&#xA;"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtEditor_db_Copy" Margin="307,167,295,93" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List mappings = new List();

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            txtEditor.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadLines(openFileDialog.FileName).First().Replace(" ","").Split(','));
        }

        if(txtEditor.Text.Count() > 0)
        {
            using(LocalDataEntities db = new LocalDataEntities())
            {
                txtEditor_db.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable');").ToList());
            }
        }

        TryAutoMapping();
        RefreshMappingBox();
    }

    private void RefreshMappingBox()
    {
        foreach (HeaderToDBMapping map in mappings) {
            txtEditor_db_Copy.Text += string.Format("{0} : {1}{2}", map.source, map.destination, Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    private void TryAutoMapping()
    {
        List<string> columnsSource = txtEditor.Text.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
        List<string> columnsDB = txtEditor_db.Text.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

        foreach (string col in columnsSource)
        {
            foreach (string colDB in columnsDB)
            {
                if (col.Equals(colDB))
                {
                    mappings.Add(new HeaderToDBMapping(col, colDB, true));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HeaderToDBMapping:

```
public class HeaderToDBMapping
    {
        public string source;
        public string destination;
        public bool autoMapped = false;

    public HeaderToDBMapping(string source, string destination, bool autoMapped)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.autoMapped = autoMapped;
    }
}
```

[image: Simple mockup]

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how can I select the columns I want to match

Answer (score 1):

i don't fully understand what you're trying to do here, But i would suggest you use `ListBox` instead of `Textbox` so you can Select the items you want to map manually.

Comment: I will look at that. I am trying to find a way to be able to pick one entry from both lists and have those be mapped together.

Comment: You can use a variable to store the index of the selected items and then check if you have both values then map them together